# Is it possible to install Ubuntu from an Ubuntu host machine onto a partition without needing to boot to install media?

Tags: system-installation

I.e. can you run the install program from an already running linux machine to install ubuntu on a separate disk/partition? I suppose it would effectively be a wubi for linux.

My use case is building a disk image from scratch. I could do it via virtual machine I think, but would be much easier if there was another option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do.

I guess you want to install in a Windows machine with Wubi that don't have internet access ?

And that you don't want to burn a CD ?

Then just copy the iso and mount it in Windows , you will launch th Wubi on the iso  and it will install without internet.

Comment: I'm trying to install ubuntu on a blank target partition from ubuntu without booting install media.